# How do you pass an IOC target into another IOC target using Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

My question is probably terrible, but here's what I'm trying to do using Castle Windsor in pseudo-code:

```
Register IFoo as Foo
Register IBar as Bar

When IFoo Is Passed Into a constructor And Being Resolved to Foo:
    Resolve IBar to Bar And pass typeof(Foo) to IBar.Create() method
        [ Resolve<IBar>().Create(typeof(Foo)) ]
```

The goal is that anytime I try to use IFoo as a dependency, I want to pass the implementation of IFoo (Foo)'s TYPE into a method on IBar - which will do some work to new up an instance of Foo and hydrate the Foo POCO.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do from this example? The only thing I can suggest is this would be something handled in the concrete type (nothing to do with Castle Windsor). So:

```
Public Class Foo
{
    Public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        bar.Create(typeof(Foo));
    }
}
```

Edit:
What you seem to be saying is you want Foo to be constructed by Bar as a [factory](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68670/The-Factory-Pattern). In which case, coupling between a factory and the types it is responsible for creating is acceptable. You could therefore pass the factory IBar into any class that requires an instance of IFoo and call the create method directly. You can then, if you needed to, switch the factory implementation mappings of IBar to give you whatever concrete IFoo's required.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. Your "Final" edit is close. However, I'd like my IBar factory to be able to churn out a concrete no matter what type is passed in.

Essentially IBar should be able to return a "Foo" or a "Class2" or a "Class3". Whatever I give it as the Type parameter in the Create() (My Create() return type is Type object). With that in mind, the Factory wouldn't know about any concrete types. It's just using Reflection to create a new instance of whatever Type I pass in.

Knowing that - any new suggestions?

Comment: Ok. Understand more what you mean now I think. So, IBar could take an IFoo in its constructor, have a property that returns the typeof, the factory gets injected in anywhere an IFoo is required, and calling the create method returns an instance? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx

Comment: Sounds pretty much correct. My Factory Create() method does a _var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);_ and returns that obj after some additional work. If I did something like IBar<IFoo>, wouldn't the Type be IFoo in the factory, though? Instead of Foo? Or would that be resolved along the way?

Comment: GetType will get you the runtime type of the object, which is what you're after. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx

Comment: I'd like to say: _Resolve<IFoo>().Resolve<IBar>().Create([insert syntax for capturing IFoo implementation's Type])_ which would results in a .Create(typeof(Foo)) call (in the Foo instance) and do it's work and return the Foo instance that I worked on as the true implementation of my IFoo.

Comment: Like I say, GetType will give you the runtime type of the interface (which is the syntax you're missing)

Comment: When I say runtime type, this can only ever be a concrete type (i.e. Foo in your example)

Comment: And yes, using the generic method would be a cleaner way of doing this. It's been a long eve :)

Comment: But....all that said: why you'd want to do this is debatable. If you start casting to the runtime type, then you're not really using interfaces as intended. See this post for an explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520694/how-to-get-actual-type-of-an-derived-class-from-its-parent-interface. Anyway...