# C# Func<T,TResult> arguments validation

Tags: c#, func

Imagine the Func `Func<Arguments, bool?>`, where `Arguments` is an abstract class. Somewhere, for some reason I create a list of these functions with all kind of derived classes as arguments. Of course the type of `Arguments` is important for validation before the `Func` is called. Is there a way to get the type of `Arguments`?

e.g.:

```
public bool? test(Arguments arg) {
    Func test    = Func<SomeArguments, bool?>;
    Type argType = GetFirstArgumentType(test); // gives SomeArguments.GetType();

    if (arg.GetType() == argType) {
        return test(new SomeArguments());
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Rather than a list of them, store them in a `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, bool?>>`. You might need to just make it a list of key value pairs if you plan to have duplicates.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to implement `GetFirstArgumentType`?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [How to get actual type of an derived class from its parent interface](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2520694/2145211) which is also applicable to derived classes?

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Yes I am ;-) Although I suspect it is undoable.. (?)

Comment: @JvN I just provided an answer - note that there are likely easier ways to accomplish this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Type.GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the `System.Type` of the first generic argument to your `Func<T,bool?>`.

That being said, it would likely be easier to store a `Dictionary<Type, Delegate>` to hold your types, and just do a direct lookup instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, " Somewhere, for some reason I create a list of these functions with all kind of derived classes as arguments. " I might suggest that you use [a parameter constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/d5x73970.aspx):

```
 public bool? test<T>(T arg)  where T :Arguments, new()
 { 
     var type = typeof(T);

     // ...              
 }
```

This will get you the type checking you describe.