# Retrieve which interface was used by the class caller at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, polymorphism

I have a class implementing 2 different interfaces, both of them sharing a method signature, let's say 'int GetChildData()'. Both of them derive from the same base interface that contains another method, let's say 'int GetBaseData()' . The concrete class will explicitly implement the 2 child methods and implicitly implement the base method. When instantiating the class as a child interface and calling the base interface method, is it possible to retrieve from inside the called class which of the child interface was used to call the method?.
Code will clarify this.
Thank you

I cannot use implicit implementation because the two child interface implementation method need to have different logic.

```cs
 internal class Program
    {


        public interface IBaseInt
        {
            int GetBaseData();
        }

        public interface IInterface_1 : IBaseInt
        {
            int getData();
        }

        public interface IInterface_2 : IBaseInt
        {
            int getData();
        }

        public class Class : IInterface_1, IInterface_2
        {
            public int GetBaseData()
            {
                //this.getData(); <---  this does not compile

                //here i need to know if 'this' was created as IInterface_1 or as IInterface_2
                if (/*???? what do i check ???*/true)
                {
                    return (this as IInterface_1).getData();
                }
                else if (/*???? what do i check ???*/true)
                {
                    return (this as IInterface_2).getData();
                }


            }
            int IInterface_1.getData() => 1;

            int IInterface_2.getData() => 2;
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IInterface_1 int1 = new Class();
            IInterface_2 int2 = new Class();

            Console.WriteLine("int 1 : " + int1.GetBaseData());
            Console.WriteLine("int 2 : " + int2.GetBaseData());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }



    }
```

result should be '1' or '2' based on the interface used.

Edit : my request is different than the one proposed as duplicate : there the user wanted to know what was the concrete type behind the interface, here i need to know if an interface was used when instantiating the type, and which one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get actual type of an derived class from its parent interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520694/how-to-get-actual-type-of-an-derived-class-from-its-parent-interface)

Comment: i edited the question to better highlight the difference between what i need and the proposed duplicate

Comment: As `class` implements both interfaces, it would not be possible to determine which interface the object is currently assigned to.  If you are able to change the `IBaseInt`, then adding the type to determine what method to use is an option - `int GetBaseData(Type t)` and check `if (t == typeof(IInterface_1))`.  Not sure what you are trying to achieve with this code.  There might be a simpler solution if you are willing to share the problem details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you may imagine, this is a gimmick that tries to circunvent a limitation around existing code. There are thousands of reference to the base method, and they are split between the two interfaces. The present inplementation solves the problem trough dependency injection and child classes inplementing one or the other interface - but that leaves me with three classes(a base and 2 derived) of which the 2 derived share a lot of code in common apart fron this specific method inplementation.

Comment: I wanted to reduce redundancy by reducing the classes from 3 to 1 class that would implement both interfaces explicitly, register it infoto the ioc container for both interfaces, and then at runtime call one method or the other based on which interface the class was assigned to by the container. Seems impossible though, we will stick to child classes. P.s. of course i cannot change the base interface method, that would require a lot of risky operations.