# How To Determine the correct or required derived class when passed with in an array of base class reference in c#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I am new to c#, im still learning, I have doubt in polymorphism
Below is the scenario

```
 public abstract class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var animals = new Animal[]
        {
            new Dog(), new Horse()
        };

        foreach (var animal in animals)
        {
             animal.Eat();
        }
    }

    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public void Eat()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Eat");
        }
    }

    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public void Bark()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bark");
        }
    }

    public class Horse : Animal
    {
        public void Neigh()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Neigh");
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, how can i access the derived type methods, do i have to type cast each animal object to its derived type ?  Do we have any design patter to resolve this problem ? please help

Comment: is this what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520694/how-to-get-actual-type-of-an-derived-class-from-its-parent-interface?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520694/how-to-get-actual-type-of-an-derived-class-from-its-parent-interface

if we have to make use of the GetType method, then we would have to introduce, too many if statements to get the desired derived type right ? is that a good approach ?

Comment: Yes, but you can clean those up following this article made by Nicklas, https://medium.com/swlh/refactoring-from-trash-to-solid-74b10005ccd3

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are looking for the composite design pattern:

> Lets you compose objects into tree structures and then work with these structures as if they were individual objects. Treat individual objects and compositions of objects uniformly.

A great way to have examples and learn how they work, especially in c#, is this repo: https://github.com/nemanjarogic/DesignPatternsLibrary
It helped me a lot to learn design pattern and get a feeling of how to implement them.

For your specific example you would need an abstract method or an extra interface for your animal specific action.

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Eat");
    }

    abstract void AnimalSpecificAction();
}
```

Which would urge you to implement this method in your implementations of animal.

```
public class Dog : Animal
{
    public override void AnimalSpecificAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bark");
    }
}

public class Horse : Animal
{
    public override void AnimalSpecificAction()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Neigh");
    }
}
```

And now you have no need to cast for calling these methods:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var animals = new Animal[]
    {
        new Dog(), new Horse()
    };

    foreach (var animal in animals)
    {
        animal.AnimalSpecificAction();
    }
}
```

I hope this helped! :)

Comment: Is it possible to do it without adding the abstract method, cause, the derived class can have its own other methods too, so this approach will likely to introduce more abstract methods, this will not work for my case i guess

Comment: If you have no way to group your methods somehow and having them implemented via an abstract method or an interface, I fear there is no possibility to call these class individual methods without casting your instance to the individual type. But if you have borders like these, it is also a hint to rethink your architectual plan. Maybe you try to group classes into one abstract class which should not be grouped into an abstract class.